# Remove array from array based on child value?

Tags: php, arrays, object, loops, recursion

I have an array of arrays,

I have posted the essential structure below,
The recursion can be of any depth.

Anyway, what I want to do is, loop over every item in the array, and if it's `['item']->data('id')` value is equal to `$id` then remove that section of the tree,

But I am not sure as to the most efficient way of doing this?

I think this might work, but am I missing something?

```
function removeKey($key, &$categories){
    foreach($categories as $k => $category){
        if($category['item']->data('id') == $key){
            unset($categories[$k]);
            return;
        }
        if(!empty($category['children']))
            removeKey($key, $category['children']);
    }
}

removeKey($id, $categories);
```

---

```
array(
    array(
        'item' => "category Object", //use ->data('id') to get the id!
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'item' => "category Object",
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'item' => "category Object",
                        'children' => array()
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'item' => "category Object",
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'item' => "category Object",
                        'children' => array()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'item' => "category Object",
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'item' => "category Object",
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'item' => "category Object",
                        'children' => array()
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'item' => "category Object",
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'item' => "category Object",
                        'children' => array()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: My code above works, however I am leaving this question open for a bit to see if anyone has a more efficient method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use either [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to traverse each child and unset the desired one.

Comment: The question is about efficiency. Is this more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter`  on the top array and then analyze each child array in the callback function. Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function removeKey($key, &$categories){
    foreach($categories as $category){//y u were using $& 
        if($category['item']->data('id') == $key){
            unset($category);
            return;
        }
        if(!empty($category['children']))
            removeKey($key, $category['children']);
    }
}

removeKey($id, $categories);
```

Comment: this is incorrect as the array is multidimensional, not single dimension.

Comment: The `&$` is so that I can edit the item as I am looping over it, otherwise it is just a copy and not a reference to the original item, hence I cannot unset it!